# How to control primefaces datatable width (over-sized data)

Tags: google-chrome, primefaces, datatable

I have some primefaces datatables that may contain very long varchar data. Letting primfaces default width will affect the web page size which causes a problem when displaying it on small tablets with Chrome.

How can I set primefaces datatables to automatically return to the line when the data size reaches certain value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<p:dataTable style="width: #{fooBean.tableWidth};" ... />` or within your `<p:column width="#{fooBean.certainColumnWidth}>`. The value of `FooBean#getTableWidth()` and `FooBean#getCertainColumnWidth()` should be set in time you retrieve your data. Be careful as in dataTable *style* attribute you can use relative values like percents, but in the column *width* attribute only pixels are allowed.